# Can't pass string from one class to another

Tags: java, string, class, methods

Hello I am trying to write a program that takes the third line from a comma separated text file then passes it through to the getData method in the WeatherDataPoint class where it splits the string into separate strings on the comma. Then I want the string variable date to be set to the value of dataLine2[7]. Then print out the date string by calling the getDate method from the driver class.

```
public class driver
```

{

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    WeatherDataPoint weather = new WeatherDataPoint();
    String dataLine1 = "";
    String inputFile = "weatherdata.csv";
    Scanner readFile = null;
    try
    {
        readFile = new Scanner (new File(inputFile));
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Error file not found");
        System.exit(1);
    }

    while (readFile.hasNextLine())
    {

        dataLine1 = readFile.nextLine();

        weather.getData(dataLine1);



    }

    System.out.println(String.format("%s",weather.getDate()));
}
```

}

```
public class WeatherDataPoint {
private String date = "";
private String temperature;


public void getData(String dataLine1)
{
    String [] dataLine2 = dataLine1.split(",");
    date = dataLine2[7];
    //long epoc = Long.parseLong(fields[DATE_POS]);
    //Date d = new Date(epoc * 1000);

}


public String getDate()
{
    //return String.format("%s", (date));
    return date;
}
```

When I run the program I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
```

Edit Here is a line from the text file

```
"1452386100","1","5","29.002591800284698","77.91272888363851","78.21244075516647","86.27","49.8",,"99","0",,"0",,"0","0","49.53002056234984","49.8","49.8",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"100",,,,,,,,,,,,
```

I made a mistake when describing the program I actually want to process all of the data in the file but skip the first three lines sorry about the confusion. Also changing dataLine[7] to dataLine[0] works.

Comment: Isn't the error message self-explanatory? You have less than 8 records on that line, hence the exception. Use your debugger. Or print values to the console.

Comment: The code in your question takes all the lines from the file, not the third line, as you stated. If this code worked, it would only print the data from the last line of the file. If your file only has three lines, I guess you'd be okay, but I doubt that is what you want...

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace this:

```
 String [] dataLine2 = dataLine1.split(",");
date = dataLine2[7];
```

With:

```
  String [] dataLine2 = dataLine1.split(",");
  date = dataLine2[dataLine2.length-1];
```

Because in array `dataLine2` you don't have element in 7th index.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to take the value from the 8th cell of the array `dataLine2`. The exception states that this index is out of bounds which means the array `dataLine2` does not have 8 cells.

This means that your String  `dataLine1` seems to not have 8 parts in a single line of the file.

Try print the size of the `dataLine2` variable so that you can see how many String parts a single line has. Then take each cell by traversing the cells in the array.

**EDIT:**

If you need to skip the first 3 rows of the file, you need to do something like this:

```
WeatherDataPoint weather = new WeatherDataPoint();
String dataLine1 = "";
String inputFile = "weatherdata.csv";
Scanner readFile = null;
try {
    readFile = new Scanner (new File(inputFile));
}
catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
    System.out.println("Error file not found");
    System.exit(1);
}

    int linesPassed = 0;
    while (readFile.hasNextLine()) {
        String row = readFile.nextLine();
        linesPassed++;
        if (linesPassed > 3) {
            dataLine1 = row;
            weather.getData(dataLine1);
        }
    }
System.out.println(String.format("%s",weather.getDate()));
```

If you need to process the whole row, it is good to save the whole String[] and process it as you wish. Here is a sample code:

private ArrayList date = new ArrayList<>();
private String temperature;

```
public void getData(String dataLine1){
    String[] rowParts =dataLine1.split(",");
    for(String part : rowParts)
        date.add(part); 
}

public String getDate() {
    //do some processing here, I`ve added a dummy print code
    String allValues = "";
    for(String val : date)
        allValues += val + " ";
    return allValues;
}
```

For a sample data in the file like this:

```
"1452386100","1","5","29.002591800284698","77.91272888363851","78.21244075516647","86.27","49.8",,"99","0",,"0",,"0","0","49.53002056234984","49.8","49.8",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"100",,,,,,,,,,,,
"1452386100","1","5","29.002591800284698","77.91272888363851","78.21244075516647","86.27","49.8",,"99","0",,"0",,"0","0","49.53002056234984","49.8","49.8",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"100",,,,,,,,,,,,
"1452386100","1","5","29.002591800284698","77.91272888363851","78.21244075516647","86.27","49.8",,"99","0",,"0",,"0","0","49.53002056234984","49.8","49.8",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"100",,,,,,,,,,,,
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7",
"0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7",
```

The output is like this:

```
"0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7" "0" "1" "2" "3" "4" "5" "6" "7"
```

Feel free to expand and modify as you need to.

Comment: Technically, 8th cell. Arrays are zero-indexed

Comment: Thanks, type error as i talk about the 8 parts of the string further on. Edited. Regards.

Comment: Thanks for your response I added an example of what a line from the data file looks like.

Comment: This is strange, I tested your code and the output is "49.8" as it should be. Check if this file is in your project folder. You might be having another file with the same name but different data in it. In order to read the file as you have pointed its path, you need to place it in your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have a date data at 8th column in csv file.